# Batch set state for Recoil

Tags: recoiljs

If I have to set states from multiple different atoms as part of some high level action user is taking, I want all subscribing components for any of the impacted atoms to be re-rendered only once when the entire states are set as a batch. Is this possible with Recoil?

Answer (score 1):

Recoil batches the state updates by default (this is also true for React state itself). If you don't want to batch the updates code wise, you could use the `useRecoilCallback` hook, something like this:

```js
const Component = () => {
  const batchUpdates = useRecoilCallback(({set}) => (valueA, valueB) => {
    set(atomA, valueA);
    set(atomB, valueB);
  }, []);

  return (
    <button onClick={() => batchUpdates(someValueA, someValueB)}>Batch Updates</button>
  );
};
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the updates are batched as long as they are performed synchronously. If you do something like `set(a, await reqA()); set(b, await reqB())` then the updates will not batch.